# Call variable without echo or print

Tags: php

I'm trying to call variable with in variable and below attempts are working fine

Attempt 01:

```
<?php
$var1 = "Hello";
echo $var1;
?>
```

Attempt 02:

```
<?php
$view = '$var1 = "Hello";
echo $var1;';
echo $view;
?>
```

But I'm trying to call variable without using "echo" or "print" command, as mentioned below

```
<?php
$view = '$var1 = "Hello";
echo $var1;';
$view;
?>
```

Is there any other way to achieve this? Please advise.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What do you mean by "call" a variable? Do you want to output it?

Comment: If you want to output it, then what is the *reason* for avoiding `echo` and `print`? (Without knowing that, any suggestions are likely to be unsuitable for the same reason).

Comment: A variable stores a value, it cannot be "called". Functions are called. [`echo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) is a language construct used to display one or more strings (literal strings or strings stored in variables or other values that are converted to strings in order to be displayed).

Comment: @Andrew I'm trying to display $var1 variable in $view without using echo or 
 print command.

Comment: @Thaju — "display in a variable" doesn't make much sense. Are you asking about how to copy the contents of one variable into another variable while adding stuff? That has nothing to do with *outputting* the result.

Comment: If you want to execute the string in php, you can use `eval( $view );`.. I dont think using `eval` is a good idea though.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info

Comment: @Eddie I got what I wanted, eval() is working perfectly Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$view = '$var1 = "Hello";
echo $var1;';
eval($view);
?>
```

Comment: ALWAYS add explanations to your answers as not everyone that reads this will know what your solution provides.